# Como puedo modificar la barra de navegación dependiendo si inicia sesión o sí no lo hace, usando angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Buenas tardes a todos me gustaría que cuando el usuario inicie sesión o que cuando el usuario termine de usar el programa, la barra de navegación muestre o no algunas opciones, así como lo hacemos al iniciar sesión en YouTube. Cuando terminamos de iniciar sesión ya no muestra nuestro usuario sino un botón u opción de "Acceder".

Para intentar resolverlo, primero cree un componente donde cree toda la barra de navegación y solo puse en el documento app.component.html lo que vendría siendo el selector de la barra de navegación. Posteriormente yo cree un servicio donde hay una variable que guardan el usuario. Cree el servicio para que se guarden los valores en un lugar centralizado, de esta manera el componente de la barra de navegación en su método ngOninit entraría y buscaría en el servicio y si la variable que guarda el usuario esta vacía que muestre opciones para que inicie sesión y si ya inicio sesión que le muestre su fotografía o otras opciones. El problema con esto es que no sé refresca o sea actualiza la barra de navegación.

La otra forma que se me ocurrió es con un Output pero parce ser que solo recibe un evento y yo solo quiero enviar el correo o el usuario para que con base a esta información opciones muestre o no datos en la barra de navegación.
Ojala me pudiera decir alguien como puedo resolver mi problema o de que otra manera puedo hacerle. Talvez sea refrescando toda la aplicación, espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Tienes que investigar sobre Observables

Comment: @Yussef gracias yuseff ,  voy a hacer lo que me dices de cualquier manera ya resolví mi problema, solamente investigue como recargar toda la pagina. Saludos Amigo